# how to find the id of an array of elements and placing them into a var using jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, get, each, attr

I have a file called text.txt that contains:

```
<li id="unic1">some text</li>
<li id="unic2">some text</li>
```

and a index.html where I try to find the id from the previous file:

```
<div id="div">alert(unic)'<div>

$(".div").load('text.txt');

$source.each(function(){
    var $unic = $("li").attr('id');
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks
edit:
thanks for response.

i found that i can gram the id's like this:

```
var unic = $('div.hidde').find('li').map(function(i, v) { return this.id; }).get();
var unic1 = $('div.hi').find('li').map(function(i, v) { return this.id; }).get();
```

and i can combine them using this script:

```
var intersection = [];       
$(liList).each(function () {
    for (i in unic) {
    for (j in unic1) {
    if (unic[i] == unic1[j]) intersection.push(unic[i]);
}
}
});
       alert(intersection);
```

another questions is how to remove the

's with the id's returned by intersection  ??

Comment: is this the complete code for your page? Please add complete code with page markup

Comment: What's $source? and $('li') inside of each $source ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the complete callback for the load function:

```
$('#result').load('text.txt', function() {
  //When load is complete
   $('.div ul').each(function(){
    var $unic = $("li").attr('id');
   });
});
```

More details on callbacks for the load method here: http://api.jquery.com/load/